# How can I randomly remove one element from a vector which satisfies given condition?

Tags: r, vector

How can I remove only AN element from a vector in R? For example,

```
x = c(1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0)
```

I want to delete only one of the zeros, randomly.  Then

```
x = c(1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2)
```

or

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0)
```

Comment: I don't see why people are voting-to-close, this question is clear.

Answer (score 3):

To randomly choose which zero gets removed, you can use

```
x[-sample(which(x == 0), 1)]
```

Obviously the above will only work if there is at least one zero in `x`.  As a safeguard, you can use an `if()` statement.

```
if(length(w <- which(x == 0))) x[-sample(w, 1)] else x
# [1] 1 2 0 3 1 4 2
if(length(w <- which(x == 0))) x[-sample(w, 1)] else x
# [1] 1 2 3 1 4 2 0
```

Searching for `11`, where there are none, we get the entire vector `x` back.

```
if(length(w <- which(x == 11))) x[-sample(w, 1)] else x
# [1] 1 2 0 3 1 4 2 0
```